# Play Framework vs Scooter Framework vs ActiveWeb -- Comparison?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, activerecord

Today there are three frameworks in Java which are in active development and share the similar philosophy for rapid web development in Java.

http://www.playframework.org/

http://www.scooterframework.com/

http://code.google.com/p/activeweb/

Any comments on pluses, minuses, advantages and disadvantages of these frameworks ?
Like:

1. Comments on Controller layer, Inheritance, etc.. ?
2. Level of "friction" in integrating application of these frameworks in other
   systems.
3. Deviation from standards and it's impacts.

{ one can append the suitable points }

Comment: I know that I will get a -1, but this frameworks are (almost) all inspired by Ruby on Rails, why don't just try Rails? (With JRuby that IS Java and runs on any Java App Server like tomcat or JBoss)

Comment: because the idea is to use Java

Comment: Learning a new programming language and it's ecosystem is a great deal of investment. may be ruby on rails is a great ecosystem, but there are many teams having huge capital expenditure in Java based technologies and human resources.

Hence it is necessary to stick to Java based frameworks at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested Play and Scooter, Scooter is for me better than Play.

Pure Java , built-in Ajax, Active Record ORM (vs JPA and Annotations with Play), code generator, easy to learn and modify !

Play is very good to scaffold with Crud Inheritance (and Tables creation with JPA) but when you want to go more far, documentation is lacking and syntax is not easy.

Scooter is based on RoR, The PHP framework which is in the same approach is YII Framework

Comment: Should we look at aspects like helpful community and core contributors too ?

Answer (score 0):

the author i think is pretty confused and i advise you to just use your own personal judgement,  try to test the three frameworks first... these frameworks are pretty pretty new. i tested all three and in my personal assessment , scooter is far more superior to the three based on my requirements. and it's more easy to learn.

all these frameworks has all the PROMISE of easeness and rapid development, if you cant assess on your own, i think dont worry to much, just pivk one, sit back, test and relax. LMAO

Comment: "..the author i think is pretty confused.." yes , I was at the time of writing the question.

Comment: "..scooter is far more superior.." Please explain your criteria/requirements which got fulfilled by Scooter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to http://joseneto.github.io/fusionwebapp/, use all you know.